# How can I programmatically determine if an application is flashing in the taskbar

Tags: window, taskbar, flashwindowex

I can use "FlashWindowEx" to make a window flash in the taskbar, but what can I call to determine if that has been done to a window? Is there a flag that gets set somewhere that I can query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's seems that such thing is not possible.
However, there may be workarounds.
For example, you may keep a boolean variable "flash = false". Then set it to "true" when you call FlashWindowEx and set to "false" in the situations in which applications typically gain focus.

References:

> http://forums.microsoft.com/MSDN/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=1846008&SiteID=1

Comment: Thanks - I was hoping there was a Win32 call I could use, but it doesn't look like it.